# Where is the main .php file located for archive of wordpress /blog? How do I force it to display all posts no matter the category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having trouble figuring this out. I Want to make the main blog archive page show all my blog posts. Currently it only displays posts that are tagged with "BLOG". This doesn't really make sense to me. Which file do I need to edit in order to fix this? Sorry if this is a dumb question I'm kind of a noobie @ Wordpress, but also did not really find any relevant answers to my question on here.

Comment: Download a copy of Wordpress, install it on your local machine, commit it to a version control system and then set about creating a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of your chosen theme, and then copy over the file(s) from your parent theme and edit them in the child (this means you will be unaffected if the parent theme is upgraded). Which theme are you using, incidentally? - the behaviour to show a post based on a 'blog' tag is quite non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

The files that make up your selected theme will be in `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME`.  If you want to modify something that shows on an archive page, that will probably be in a file called archive.php (see: [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy))